# Proving a relation between inradius ,circumradius and exradii in a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Prove that in a triangle $$r^2+r_1^2+r_2^2+r_3^2=16R^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$ where the symbols have their usual meanings. I am looking for a **smaller** or **elegant** proof using trigonometry. A geometric proof would be super cool. I did prove it but it took me ages to do the calculation. Thanks.

Comment: use $r_a=\frac{\Delta}{s-a}$ etc and $r=\frac{\Delta}{s}$, $R=\frac{abc}{4\Delta}$

Comment: There is a semi-geometric proof on pp. 12-13 of Coxeter's Introduction to Geometry that uses Heron's formula and some geometry.

Comment: A very interesting proof can be found [here](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2006volume6/FG200639.pdf).

Comment: On a quick Google search: https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20131030074420AA7sk6d

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks, that's a very interesting article.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Using $r=4R\sin\dfrac A2\sin\dfrac B2\sin\dfrac C2$ and  $r_1=4R\sin\dfrac A2\cos\dfrac B2\cos\dfrac C2$ etc.

$r^2=16R^2\sin^2\dfrac A2\sin^2\dfrac B2\sin^2\dfrac C2=2R^2(1-\cos A)(1-\cos B)(1-\cos C)$

$r_1^2=16R^2\left(\sin^2\dfrac A2\cos^2\dfrac B2\cos^2\dfrac C2\right)=2R^2(1-\cos A)(1+\cos B)(1+\cos C)$

For the right hand side, use $\dfrac a{\sin A}=2R$ etc.

and $\sin^2A+\sin^2B+\sin^2C=2+2\cos A\cos B\cos C$ ([Proof](http://openstudy.com/updates/4e4e20870b8b958804a26a8d))